# Choose certificate popup list is empty in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, certificate, internet-explorer-8

Trying to solve the issue choosing certificate in Internet Explorer 8 on Windows 7 since the website I am trying to login requires a certificate. Here the popup with empty list (image link below).

Basic troubleshooting has been done including:

- Installing certificate both with regular and admin users;
- Running Internet Explorer with admin rights;
- Running Internet Explorer in safe mode (add-on free)
- Performing Internet Explorer Reset through Internet Options -> Advanced.
- Clearing SSL cache.

Several PCs with the same configuration run fine at this point. Certificates were also imported successfully on this machine.

[image]

Comment: The only reason I can think is that, the certificate your expecting to use, isn't compataible with IE8  Has this ever worked?

Comment: Such certificates work correctly on at least IE7+. Other machines with IE8 and certificates like this work fine.

Comment: Configuration of IE8 is identical?

Comment: Confuration is identical

Comment: What type of hash is the certificate using?